# How to write length function for all Monoids

Tags: haskell

I'm playing around with rewriting simple functions in different ways and I clearly misunderstand some core concepts. Is there a better way to work with limited types like these?

```
mlength :: Monoid m => m -> Int
mlength mempty   = 0
mlength (l <> r) = mlength l + mlength r
```

It fails compilation with the following error:

```
Parse error in pattern: l <> r
```

I can see that my usage of `<>` is misguided because there are multiple correct matches for `l` and `r`. Even though it looks like it doesn't matter which value is assigned, a value still has to be assigned in the end. Maybe there's a way for me to assert this decision for specific Monoid instances?

```
"ab" == ""   <> "ab" 
"ab" == "a"  <> "b" 
"ab" == "ab" <> ""
```

Comment: You can’t match on `(a <> b)`: `<>` is a function, but you can only pattern match on constructors. In fact, you don’t know anything at all about `m`, aside from the fact that it’s a `Monoid`, so you can’t pattern-match on it; in fact, the only thing you can do at all is call the `Monoid` functions on it. Still, it _feels_ like it should be possible to write this function — I wonder how you could do it…

Comment: Fair distinction between constructors and functions. I think I get a little mixed up because `(:)` seems to be used as both? Not entirely sure how that works.

Comment: `(:)` is a constructor, which also happens to be an operator. I think the issue here is that there are three separate but related concepts: (1) Functions, which process one or more arguments to produce an output; _(oops, submitted in the middle of a comment; I’ll continue writing in the next comment)_

Comment: …output; (2) Data constructors, which are the primitives used to construct a data type; (3) Operators, which are special symbols which can be placed between two expressions rather than before them as with a normal function. The confusing thing is that constructors can be used as functions, but functions cannot be used in pattern-matching while constructors can; also, both functions and constructors can be declared to be either ‘normal’ identifiers or operators.

Comment: `mempty` is here seen as *just* a variable, not something equal to `memtpy`.

Comment: The `length` is by the way already fully defined on `Foldable`s, hence it wil work on `Tree`s, `Maybe`s, etc.

Comment: @codenoodle all constructors are functions, but not all functions are constructors

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `Semigroup` and `Monoid` interfaces provide a means to build up values, `(<>)`. They don't, however, give us a way to break down or otherwise extract information from values. That being so, a `length` generalised beyond some specific type requires a different abstraction.

As discussed in the comments to [chi's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60237132/2751851), while `Data.Foldable` offers a generalised `length :: Foldable t => t a -> Int`, it isn't quite what you were aiming at -- in particular, the connection between `Foldable` and `Monoid` is that foldable structures can be converted to lists/the free monoid, and not that foldables themselves are necessarily monoids.

One other possibility, which is somewhat obscure but closer to the spirit of your question, is the [`Factorial` class from the *monoid-subclasses* package](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/monoid-subclasses-1.0.1/docs/Data-Semigroup-Factorial.html), a subclass of `Semigroup`. It is built around `factors :: Factorial m => m -> [m]`, which splits a value into irreducible factors, undoing what `sconcat` or `mconcat` do. A generalised `length :: Factorial m => m -> Int` can then be defined as the length of the list of factors. In any case, note that we still end up needing a further abstraction on the top of `Semigroup`/`Monoid`.

Comment: This `Factorial` class really does seem closer to the kind of thing I'm looking for. It's easy to see how to implement `length :: Factorial m => m -> Int`, but I'm having trouble figuring out what "a further abstraction on the top of `Semigroup` / `Monoid`" would be.

Comment: @codenoodle By "further abstraction", I just meant `Factorial` itself, or some other hypothetical class which would enable us to express `length`. I have tweaked that sentence to clarify it.

Answer (score 11):

A monoid, in the general case, has no notion of length. Take for instance [`Sum Int`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Data-Monoid.html#t:Sum), which is `Int` equipped with addition for its monoidal operation. We have

```
Sum 3 <> Sum 4 = Sum 7 = Sum (-100) <> Sum 7 <> Sum (100)
```

What should be its "length"? There is no real notion of length here, since the underlying type is `Int`, which is not a list-like type.

Another example: [`Endo Int`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Data-Monoid.html#t:Endo) which is `Int -> Int` equipped with composition. E.g.

```
Endo (\x -> x+1) <> Endo (\x -> x*2) = Endo (\x -> 2*x+1)
```

Again, no meaningful "length" can be defined here.

You can browse [`Data.Monoid`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Data-Monoid.html) and see other examples where there is no notion of "length".

[`Const a`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Data-Functor-Const.html#t:Const) is also a (boring) monoid with no length.

Now, it is true that lists `[a]` form a monoid (the free monoid over `a`), and length can indeed be defined there. Still, this is only a particular case, which does not generalize.

Comment: Well it does generalise, but in a completely different direction - not to all monoids, but to all `t a` where `t` is `Foldable`. And monoids are key to the definition of `Foldable` so perhaps there is some deeper connection (even though, as you point out, a `length` function for an arbitrary monoid doesn't really make sense).

Comment: @RobinZigmond Sure, but that's cheating (IMO), since any lawful `Foldable t` instance is uniquely determined by its `toList :: t a -> [a]`. In my eye, saying that list length generalizes to any foldable, amounts to saying that list length generalizes to anything that can be converted into a list, which is pretty much unsurprising. Perhaps my lack of enthusiasm for `Foldable` in general prevents me to appreciate the generalization.

Comment: @chi "any lawful Foldable t instance is uniquely determined by its `toList :: t a -> [a]`" This would seem to disagree: http://comonad.com/reader/2015/free-monoids-in-haskell/

Comment: Ok these examples are excellent. Clearly some monoids don't really have a computable "length." However, I feel like there is still a way for me to write the function such that calling `mlength` on foldable monoids will terminate with an `Int`, and calling it on other instances means it simply won't terminate. This by no means is _useful_ but I'm just doing this to try and learn Haskell.

Comment: @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica I somehow agree. Still, when we start to consider bottom or infinite values, then many instances become unlawful. E.g. we do not have `[0..] == [0..]`.  Further, even if we replace `toList` with `toFreeMonoid` my argument should stand. We do have a length notion for the free monoid (and we now do not have it for lists, since we include infinite ones), and `Foldable` does not really generalize much over that.

Comment: @codenoodle You could instead define your own `class Monoid a => SizedMonoid a where mlength :: a -> Int` and define appropriate instances only when meaningful. No need to allow for non termination elsewhere.